# Deriving from VirtualizingStackPanel does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I’m trying to create virtualizing uniform grid, so I took some code from [here](ftp://ftp.charlespetzold.com/AppsCodeMarkup/Chapter%2012/DuplicateUniformGrid/UniformGridAlmost.cs) which creates a panel where I can set the number of columns,
 and it works fine, and it’s about 3-4 times faster than standard uniform grid (I tested it on a complicated item template for listbox with lots of records). 
So I thought I change the base control from Panel to VirtualizingStackPanel but as soon as I do this, no records show. Any Ideas why?
Here is my working code:

Change below to derive from VirtualizingPanel or VirtualizingStackPanel, and it won't work anymore :(

```
public class MyUniformGrid : Panel // VirtualizingStackPanel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(int), typeof(MyUniformGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public int Columns
    {
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
    }

    private int Rows => (InternalChildren.Count + Columns - 1) / Columns;

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size sizeAvailable)
    {
        var sizeChild = new Size(sizeAvailable.Width / Columns, sizeAvailable.Height / Rows);

        double maxwidth = 0;
        double maxheight = 0;

        foreach (UIElement child in InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Measure(sizeChild);

            maxwidth = Math.Max(maxwidth, child.DesiredSize.Width);
            maxheight = Math.Max(maxheight, child.DesiredSize.Height);
        }
        return new Size(Columns * maxwidth, Rows * maxheight);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size sizeFinal)
    {
        var sizeChild = new Size(sizeFinal.Width / Columns, sizeFinal.Height / Rows);
        for (var index = 0; index < InternalChildren.Count; index++)
        {
            var row = index / Columns;
            var col = index % Columns;
            var rectChild = new Rect(new Point(col * sizeChild.Width, row * sizeChild.Height), sizeChild);

            InternalChildren[index].Arrange(rectChild);
        }
        return sizeFinal;
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <uniformGridDemo:MyUniformGrid Columns="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

code behind

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            list.Add(i);
        }
        MyListBox.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: That's because implementing custom virtualized panel is not as simple as just inheriting from VirtualizingPanel. See here for an example of custom virtualized panel: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75847/Virtualizing-WrapPanel

Comment: @Evk 
 
Thank you for your comment, I thought it would be simple because if I simply change ItemsPanelTemplate to VirtualizingStackPanel it works just fine, but obviously I don't get the columns then. So if this virtualizing panel works out of the box, I don't understand how it does not work, when deriving from it

Comment: VirtualizingPanel is abstract class, so it does _not_ work out of the box, you have to add an implementation. VirtualizingStackPanel does provide such implementation, but to arrange items in a stack manner, so you cannot reuse it.

Comment: I would avoid `VirtualizingStackPanel` and just roll my own implementation. See [this blog post](https://rhnatiuk.wordpress.com/2006/12/13/implementing-a-virtualized-panel-in-wpf/) for a list of reading required.

Comment: @ghord Hi, I'm testing this approach, it pretty much works out of the box. It is very fast to virtualize, but then scrolling is very slow as the datatemplate for each item grows.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on `VirtualizingStackPanel`, but if you just want to resolve the item display problem, below would work.

```
 public class MyUniformGrid :  VirtualizingStackPanel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(int), typeof(MyUniformGrid), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(1, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure));

    public int Columns
    {
        set { SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value); }
        get { return (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty); }
    }

    private int Rows
    {
        get
        {                
            return (InternalChildren.Count + Columns - 1) / Columns;
        }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size sizeAvailable)
    {
        base.MeasureOverride(sizeAvailable);
        var sizeChild = new Size(sizeAvailable.Width / Columns, sizeAvailable.Height / Rows);

        double maxwidth = 0;
        double maxheight = 0;

        foreach (UIElement child in this.InternalChildren)
        {
            child.Measure(sizeChild);

            maxwidth = Math.Max(maxwidth, child.DesiredSize.Width);
            maxheight = Math.Max(maxheight, child.DesiredSize.Height);
        }
        return new Size(Columns * maxwidth, Rows * maxheight);

    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size sizeFinal)
    {
        base.ArrangeOverride(sizeFinal);
        var sizeChild = new Size(sizeFinal.Width / Columns, sizeFinal.Height / Rows);
        for (var index = 0; index < InternalChildren.Count; index++)
        {
            var row = index / Columns;
            var col = index % Columns;
            var rectChild = new Rect(new Point(col * sizeChild.Width, row * sizeChild.Height), sizeChild);

            InternalChildren[index].Arrange(rectChild);
        }
        return sizeFinal;
    }
}
```

But `VirtualizingStackPanel` is much complex implementation then `overriding` `MeasureOverride` & `ArrangeOverride` methods and arranging items. you need to process the scroll info and respect to that addition & removal of items in panel needs to be handled. So even after displayed items completely you may not get the desired performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it, its super fast, but it does not display properly :( boxes have some content cut out, and the scroller behaves very strange. Looks like I will have to have a deep dive into whats going on inside the virtualizing stack panel. I was hoping that there will be a simpler solution.

Comment: @adminSoftDK yes, as I said in my answer scrolling info is the key for VirtualizingStackPanel. even though items are arranged in grid manner the scroll is displayed as they are arranged vertically. If i'll get time then I'll look into VirtualizingStackPanel more. If you find any answer meanwhile, please let me know too.

Comment: Thank you, I'll let you know if I find something :) I'm actually suprised that more people don't have this problem as uniform grid can allow to do some really nice designs but its very slow when trying to render many records.

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented something similar in Silverlight by applying styles to `ListBox` and replacing the `ItemsPanelTemplate` with a `WrapPanel`. I've used the same in Windows Phone and WPF projects with no issues.

Styles

```
<!--Wrapping ListBox Styles-->
<Style x:Key="StretchedItemContainerStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ListBox_HorizontalWrapStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource StretchedItemContainerStyle}"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" >
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<!--End Wrapping ListBox Styles-->
```

Xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" Style="StaticResource ListBox_HorizontalWrapStyle">
```

You should also be able to style the `WrapPanel` for what ever other performance gains can be attained from it.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I fail to see how is this going to increase performance as the wrappanel does not virtualize. Because the main problem is that, if there are 200 records, it will draw all 200 of them which is slow. By virtualizing it would only draw whats visible and then add to when scrolling.